# What does static DHCP mean? Static Dynamic is confusing

Tags: networking, router, home-networking, dhcp, static-ip

I've found some home wireless routers/ADSL+ modems (ZyXEL 660) talking about Static DHCP, when refering to assosiating a specific MAC to an IP, but still serve the configuration over DHCP.

Doesn't this have another name? What does Cisco call this feature (that I know supports because I've used long time ago)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A DHCP reservation. Cisco refers to it as "Static DHCP".

More information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Overview). (See "Manual allocation").

Comment: beat me by 36 seconds...so you get a +1 for quick response ;-)

Answer (score 11):

You're talking about a DHCP reservation.  This is actually a common feature but little-known by most folks.  It's quite useful for locking an IP address to a machine, but wanting to keep centralized control over its settings for DNS and default gateway, etc.  Very useful.

Answer (score 6):

My router calls it IP-MAC binding

Also heard it refered to as DCHP reservation

Answer (score 3):

**Static DHCP**  : Static DHCP is where you can specify the MAC address of any machine in DHCP server so that PC with stated MAC address will always get the same IP address from DHCP server because MAC address is bound with IP Address in DHCP server.

**Dynamic DHCP** : here no Bind of MAC address and IP address so when a user newly request for IP address from DHCP server he will get new IP address on each request.